# Loqate address suggestions for Chinese countries

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, salesforce-commerce-cloud, oracle-commerce-cloud

working on project where requirement is to show Chinese address in English(US). I went through the documentation found nothing helpful. requirement is whenever user starts typing the suggestion of address should be in english instead of chinese. Using loqaecte for address suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your sure you use UTF-8 in the GET request?

All you need is to specify the charset in your request.